# ADF v2 - Web Activity- POST output not retrievable

Tags: azure-data-factory

With Azure Data Factory v2, I created Web Activity using the POST method and got the desired response output.
But can't get the rows data from the output response in the next activity.

How do I reference columns in the rows in this output?
The data in the rows doesn't have any headers.

```
{
"Tables": [
    {
        "TableName": "Table_0",
        "Columns": [
            {
                "ColumnName": "MyFieldA",
                "DataType": "String",
                "ColumnType": "string"
            },
            {
                "ColumnName": "MyFieldB",
                "DataType": "String",
                "ColumnType": "string"
            }
        ],
        "Rows": [
            [
                "ABCDEF",
                "AAAABBBBBCCCDDDDD"
            ],
            [
                "CCCCCCC",
                "CCCCCCC"
            ],
```

I can't reference the value in the rows 
I've tried numerous things
e.g. @activity('WebActivity').output.Rows

Nothing seems to work.
What's the point of getting a response from a web activity and then not being able to reference the output in data factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example.

@activity('WebActivity').output.Tables[0].Rows
will return the following:

```
[
    [
        "ABCDEF",
        "AAAABBBBBCCCDDDDD"
    ],
    [
        "CCCCCCC",
        "CCCCCCC"
    ]
]
```

If you want to access even deeper, you just need to specify the index.
@activity('WebActivity').output.Tables[0].Rows[0][0] will return ABCDEF

If you need to automate this, you can have a pattern of foreach with an execute pipeline inside passing an array as a parameter until you get to the properties that you need.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried various version of the above but not quite there yet. I do execute pipeline passing in parameter @activity('WebActivity').output.Tables[0].Rows which provides the next pipeline array with the data rows as per your example above. "just the rows" and use a for each look and then I'm trying to reference the rows in the array with @{item().Rows[0]} or variations of. But it doesn't work... The rows doesn't have any tags and I'm not sure what the syntax is to reference them. I have also tried @{item().[0]} and so on

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Pacodel!!! You've helped me out.
And to use in the a For Each Loop and Array, when I pass in the Rows to my Execute pipeline activity @activity('WebActivity').output.Tables[0].Rows:

```
[
   [
    "ABCDEF",
    "AAAABBBBBCCCDDDDD"
   ],
   [
    "CCCCCCC",
    "CCCCCCC"
   ]
]
```

I can use the following to reference the rows:

```
@{item()[0]}
@{item()[1]}
```

I use the @item to populate parameters in a stored procedure activity which loads my table

Thanks